# Saving Service Data To Global Variable in Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controllers

I am unable to update the geodata array inside places.success function. console.log prints JSON object inside function, however outside function it's undefined.

I want to access geodata array contents outside function call. Any code snippets will help.

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope','places', function($scope,places)     {
  $scope.mapCenter = {
  lat: 40.741934,
  lng: -74.004897,
  zoom: 17
  };
  var geodata=new Array();
  places.success(function(data) {
     geodata = data;
     console.log('inside'+geodata); //geodata is having a json value here, returning from data. 
   });
   console.log(geodata); //why geodata is still undefined here, I assigned value 
   }]);
```

Solved the problem:

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope','places', function($scope,places)     {
  $scope.mapCenter = {
      lat: 40.741934,
      lng: -74.004897,
      zoom: 17
    };
  var geodata=new Array();
  var callme=function(data){
    console.log('call'+data)
    $scope.mapMarkers = geodataToMarkers(data)
  }
  places.success(function(data) {
    geodata = data
    console.log('inside'+data); //geodata is having a json value here, returning from data. 
    callme(data);
  });
 }]);
```

Comment: so how are you calling places.success?

Comment: It's a callback for angular service:

'app.factory('places', ['$http', function($http) {
  return $http.jsonp('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=geosearch&gsradius=5000&gscoord=40.741934%7C-74.004897&gslimit=30&format=json&callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
         .success(function(data) {
           return data;
         })
         .error(function(data) {
           return data;
         });
}]);'

Comment: can you show us that service?

Comment: It looks like your success event callback might be asynchronous, so the geodata is not set right after calling the places.success(...) function, however it should be an empty array, not undefined

Comment: you have a problem with asynchronous calls, luckily it seems that you're returning a promise, so you can just use the `places.then();` method

Comment: IfTrue, Using scope also, it's same. Undefined outside function.

Comment: @simdrouin its getting the correct result, his `.success()` is firing upon replacing the original input, since `data` isn't being passed into the anonymous function, it's overwriting the `new Array()` with the contents of `data`, which is `undefined`

Comment: 'places.then()' also says undefined. Yes you are right it's asynchronous call, hence I am facing this issue. Any idea how to resolve this.

Comment: @iam-decoder I am getting the log in console in below order, which means that code inside function was called after outside console.log statement,

[]
inside[object Object]

Comment: @iam-decoder how exactly do you know what's being passed to the anonymous function (callback of success) since we don't have the details of the `places.success` function?

Comment: How do you plan on using geodata array in real application? Your solution might just depend on that. Since it is async, console.log will give you the behavior you are getting. As you can see it first prints [], an empty array and then [object Object]. What do you need to do with geodata array after setting it asynchronously. If it is for display on UI, define it on scope so digest cycle can automatically refresh the UI when you change it in async block.

Comment: @simdrouin The service is defined as below, which has definition for places.success function:

    app.factory('places', ['$http', function($http) { return      $http.jsonp('en.wikipedia.org/w/…) .success(function(data) { return data; }) .error(function(data) { return data; }); }]);

Comment: @AshutoshUpadhyay This json data has information of mapMarkers, which will be first parsed, and then parsed json will be passed to a directive.

Comment: @IfTrue, dont you expect exceptions if places is not injected?

ApoorvGupta, your answer will depend on how you want to use geodata.

Comment: @IfTrue point is simple. If places is not injected, you would get cannot read then of undefined instead of places.then itself being undefined. Hope the point is clear.

Comment: @ApoorvGupta Ok, that makes sense then, this is asynchronous so it explains why your variable is not set right after the call to success.  You can try to display the value of the geodata in a `setTimeout(function () { console.log(geodata); }, 1000);` function, just to see it's been set correctly after 1 second (or more if your service runs slower than that), but the best would be that your callback function calls another function when the success callback is done

Comment: @AshutoshUpadhyay I had already injected places in controller, as shown in code snippet in post.

Comment: Thats correct I noticed that Apoorv. Writing a potential answer to what I understand your query is.

Answer (score 0):

Because places.success is asycnronous, after calling this method it move to console.log(geodata) and it will print empty array not null. You must wait for the response of having the data.

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope','places', function($scope,places)     {
  $scope.mapCenter = {
  lat: 40.741934,
  lng: -74.004897,
  zoom: 17
  };
  var geodata=new Array();
  places.success(function(data) {
     geodata = data;
      console.log('inside'+geodata); //You can receive here data
   });
    // console.log(geodata); Because places.success is asycnronous, its the empty array not null
   }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is a directive (say my-marker) to display a geolocation on map, you may have an ng-repeat in your template html that would run through geodata variable. Hence you should define it on controller scope.

**Controller code fragment**

```
$scope.geodata = [];
places.success(function (data) {
  $scope.geodata = data; //Note depending on how your promise is resolved you may have to do **data.data** instead of **data**
});
```

**Template**

```
<my-marker ng-repeat="geoDatum in geoData" geo-datum="geoDatum"></my-marker>
```

NOTE: I have made stated assumptions around your directive.

Answer (score 0):

Save data in your service(from your comments) like so:

```
app.service('places', ['$http', function($http) {
  this.dataFromService = []; 
  this.getData = function(){
   return $http.jsonp('en.wikipedia.org/w/…') .success(function(data) { 
     this.dataFromService = data; }); 
   }
}
]);
```

Then in your controller call the service then use .then() to access the data after the promise is resolved:

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope','places', function($scope,places)     {
  $scope.mapCenter = {
  lat: 40.741934,
  lng: -74.004897,
  zoom: 17
  };
  var geodata=new Array();
  places.getData().$promise.then(function(){
  geodata = this.dataFromService;
  });
  console.log(geodata);
}]);
```

For more reference: http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/Oct/24/AngularJs-and-Promises-with-the-http-Service

Comment: the code has serious errors. There is no $scope in services. And there are more issues that I will leave at you to understand and point out.

Comment: Relax simple error - meant this not scope. What other errors?

Comment: First of all what are you really trying to solve? I don't see your suggested approach adding any value.

Comment: I am not sure why you are being so aggressive but from the comments the main issue the OP has stated was he was not able to access that data after the promise was resolved - he then went on to say .then() was undefined. This approach shows him how to save the data AFTER the promise has been resolved which required a) returning the promise in the service and b) using $promise.then in the controller. If you still don't understand this I can clarify further but I feel it is pretty straight forward really. There is a link included that you can go and learn more about the topic as well.

Comment: Sorry buddy not being aggressive. I just see issues with the code. Please see below. The code we enter at SOF should be accurate to maintain standards.
1. you changed jsonp to json. X-domain issues. A minor one. 
2. If your dataFromService variable is defined in service, how are you really accessing it using this.dataFromService inside the callback? Inside the callback, "this" points to the service instance? 
3. Service is defined as a factory. Even "this" instead of $scope is wrong. If you use .service instead of .factory, thats a little better.
Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Thanks will update it now. I typically use services for this (in comments OP had it as factory and I didn't realize that) hence why I used this (didn't realize it functions differently in factories, I will look more into this).

Comment: Sure. Read more about services. All the 3 ways. Service, factory and providers.